# What should I consider when buying Bass pedals?

Tags: bass-guitar, electric-bass-guitar, effects-pedal

I've been playing guitar for some time, and recently switched over to bass. I've picked up a decent practice amp and have been diligently plucking away. I want to start digging into the different tones I can get out of my bass guitar and amp.

I'm looking to pick up a few pedals; what are some of the first pedals I should be looking to get, or what sort of checklist should I go through to determine that? Looking to a good variety of tones for most popular music types on a bass guitar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really depends on what you're looking for. If you want a more aggressive sound (usually used in punk/metal) bands, you can go for a distortion or an overdrive pedal.

You might also find useful a compressor pedal for live shows. If you want loops, you'll need a looper pedal. I personally like the Fuzz pedals and use them quiet often. Many bassists use wah wah pedals (like guitarists) and envelope filters, but I'm not a big fan of the former; I like the latter though.

What you need to do is to check out pedal reviews on Youtube and see what sounds you like and want. A good channel is [Basstheworld.com](http://www.basstheworld.com/), where they review pedals (amongst other things). They have a site as well as a Youtube channel and they have reviewed quite a few pedals.

Another thing you can do is to go to a local store and try them out. This will be the best, because you can see them for yourself and try them and see if you like them or not.